# Merge these two json objects based on a specific key inside of them in python? (Plz view example)

Tags: python, django, algorithm

Is there a way to match these json objects based on the "matchID" and make them into one object with merged data? I basically want these to make a table that contains the stat of each player participating on the same match id.

Input:

```
    data_list = [
    {
        "kloweritotv#3560772":[
            {
                "kd":2,
                "kills":6,
                "teamPlacement":3,
                "damageDone":2388,
                "matchID":"12887455297423544724"
            },
            {
                "kd":1,
                "kills":4,
                "teamPlacement":14,
                "damageDone":1828,
                "matchID":"11929202821836542057"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "Stylnox07":[
            {
                "kd":4.5,
                "kills":9,
                "teamPlacement":3,
                "damageDone":2549,
                "matchID":"12887455297423544724"
            },
            {
                "kd":1.5,
                "kills":3,
                "teamPlacement":14,
                "damageDone":1008,
                "matchID":"11929202821836542057"
            }
    }
]
```

Desired output (Pseudo code):

```
[
   {
      "matchid":12887455297423544724,
      "kloweritotv":{
         "kd":2,
         "kills":6,
         "teamPlacement":3,
         "damageDone":2388,
         "matchID":"12887455297423544724"
      },
      "Stylnox07":{
         "kd":4.5,
         "kills":9,
         "teamPlacement":3,
         "damageDone":2549,
         "matchID":"12887455297423544724"
      }
   },
   {
      "matchid":11929202821836542057,
      "kloweritotv":{
         "kd":1,
         "kills":4,
         "teamPlacement":14,
         "damageDone":1828,
         "matchID":"11929202821836542057"
      },
      "Stylnox07":{
         "kd":1.5,
         "kills":3,
         "teamPlacement":14,
         "damageDone":1008,
         "matchID":"11929202821836542057"
      }
   }
]
```

Any information would definitely be very helpful! TIA!

Update: Took out the extra match for easier understanding. In other words, if User 1 has match_id 123 and user 2 also has match_id 123 - They should both be merged under one match_id 123 with their respective data.

Comment: Merge them how? I see a combination of min and max in the fields...

Comment: Where has `"matchID":"4196836767861917674"` gone in the desired output. It appears to be missing and therefore not consistent with the input.

Comment: @DaniMesejo So you see how the input contains an user and all of his matches. Basically each match has an ID that the other user may also be part of. So if they both have the same match id, they should be under one match id and their stats under that match id as stated on the output. Also, i don't want to make match_id a key because later on it would be harder to iterate over that if id's are all different.

Comment: @D.L I updated the question, what i wanted to do with that example was that if the match_id does not exist in both players then we don't merge it. But we can ignore that case for now. I care more about the first question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: That's alright! I got the solution already. No need to get all petty. Anyways thanks for writing something haha. And you shouldn't downvote the solution lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def collect_data(key_id, match_id):
    d = []
    for k1 in data_list:
        for k2 in k1:
            if k2 != key_id: continue
            for e in k1[k2]:
                if e.get('matchID', None) == match_id:
                    e1 = e.copy()
                    e1.pop('matchID')
                    d.append(e1)
    return d

dics = {}
for k1 in data_list:
    for k2 in k1:        
        for e in k1[k2]:
            m = e.get('matchID', None)
            if m is None: continue
            if not m in dics: dics[m] = {}
            dics[m].update({k2: collect_data(k2, m)})
```